# Set Variable only get the last value in a loop in Symfony Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am very new in Symfony and I have a problem in my twig. I just don't know how to do it :(

```
 {% set trans_number = '' %}
   {% for tran in trans %}
     {% set trans_number = tran.transNumber %}
       {{dump(trans_number)}}
   // this is what I get when dumping inside the loop: string(10) "1073110793" string(10) "1073145793" string(12) "646721454679"
   {% endfor %}
```

But when I tried to dump it outside the loop:

```
    {% set trans_number = '' %}
   {% for tran in trans %}
     {% set trans_number = tran.transNumber %}
   {% endfor %}
  {{dump(trans_number)}}
  // I get only the last value string(12) "646721454679"
```

Now my question is, how can I access all the values assigned to the trans_number outside the loop?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct with the variable scope and handling the scope access by declaring `trans_number` before the loop, however you're misinterpreting how `set` works with Twig, or just how variables work.

When you use `set trans_number = tran.transNumber`, you're just assigning a new value to the `trans_number` variable each time. When you move the `dump` outside of the loop, you're no longer dumping the new value of `trans_number` through each iteration.

If you wish to build a list of values into `trans_number`, then you need to initialize `trans_number` as a list and append to it through each iteration of the `for` loop:

```
{% set trans_number = [] %}
{% for tran in trans %}
    {% set trans_number = trans_number|merge([tran.transNumber]) %}
{% endfor %}
{{dump(trans_number)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for the answer to the **question in the title of the question**:

You could use the **last** Filter

Example:

```
{{ dump( (trans|last) ) }}
```

Source: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html